# Selecting multiple targets with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently found a jquery datepicker for my website. I have installed the relevent files but am having a prioblem as I have two date fields on my page that the datepicker should target. Currently it only works on the first of the two fields, even when both the fields have the same id and name ("date"). The javascript that the datepicker uses is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"date",
        dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
        isStripped:false,
        cellColorScheme:"armygreen",
        /*selectedDate:{                This is an example of what the full configuration offers.
            day:5,                      For full documentation about these settings please see the full version of the code.
            month:9,
            year:2006
        },*/
        yearsRange:[1978,2020],
        limitToToday:false,
        //cellColorScheme:"beige",

        imgPath:"img/",
        weekStartDay:1
    });
};
```

I don't know how to add another target to the target line in this code Ideally id like it to target "dateA" and "dateB".

Any ideas? sorry if im being daft!
John

Comment: You cannot have two elements with the same ID

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using JQueryUI's datepicker since it is the most reliable.

If you are unfamiliar with JQueryUI, visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/ (this showcases what it is capable of).

To see a live demo of datepicker, go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/. **MAKE SURE TO LOOK AT OPTIONS/EVENTS/METHODS!**.

As for the code...

Put these scripts in your `<head>`, which will give you scripts for *JQuery* & *JQueryUI*:

```
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            altField: "#result1, #result2",
            altFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
            //altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy" //another format
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

For the body, I used the following:

```
<p>
Date: 
<input type="text" id="datepicker"> 
<input type="text" id="result1"> 
<input type="text" id="result2">
</p>​
```

To visually see what I did, I made a quick demo. Feel free to use it!

http://jsfiddle.net/6UnTh/23/

To customize your theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and download the necessary files (otherwise use the one I provided in the `<head>`).

Hope this helps! Make sure to use the other options/methods JQueryUI has to offer! HAPPY CODING!

Links:
JQuery (http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

JQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

***EDIT: (I HAVE UPDATED THE DEMO!):***

http://jsfiddle.net/6UnTh/27/

Comment: Hello Dom, thankyou for your help, I have done as you have checked out your jsfiddle page, when I select the date in the first box it then fills the remaining 2 boxes with the date picked in the first. What I am hoping to do is have two seperate dates that use the datepicker, the first is an arrival date, then the next is a departure date. I can get the datepicker to appear on the arrival date box, but not on the departure date box as the datepicker is only targeting the arrival date. Sorry if i'm not making sense!

Comment: @TranquilityEden Sorry about that! I have updated the demo! Let me know if that's what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                new JsDatePick({
                    useMode:2,
                    target:"inputField1",
                    dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"

                });
                                new JsDatePick({
                    useMode:2,
                    target:"inputField2",
                    dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"

                });
                                new JsDatePick({
                    useMode:2,
                    target:"inputField3",
                    dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"

                });
            };
        </script>

<input type="text" size="12" id="inputField1" name="txt_ordate" class="ErrorField">
<input type="text" size="12" id="inputField2" name="txt_ordate" class="ErrorField">
<input type="text" size="12" id="inputField3" name="txt_ordate" class="ErrorField">
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be helpful and complement your code snippet =)

Comment: This approach caused a null error in JsDatePick, but the example given on javascriptcalendar.org shows multiple calendars, and they work. Viewing source on that page: http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php